# Does the order of methods in my .m file matter to the compiler?

Tags: objective-c

I think that i have noticed moving certain methods around causes errors when i compile that are remedied by putting the method back where it was.

am i making this up? is there are rhyme or reason to the order that these need to be in? is decided by the order of my .h? what about delegate methods and inherited methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but only if you reference a method in an earlier place without declaring it elsewhere. You may want to declare your method in your main `@implementation` or stick it into a [class extension](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocCategories.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH20-SW2) in your implementation (.m) file.

Comment: funny thing is that i first noticed this because of configureCell:atIndexPath which is not my method. Makes sense, I knew that about C but thought it didn't apply in Obj-c

Comment: The LLVM compiler runs over the file twice so from the compiler's point of view order doesn't matter.

Comment: yeah, things changed around 4.2.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't matter anymore.